# I would like some SQL syntax for checking if the value differs from the one below it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like some SQL (Sql Server2008R2) syntax for checking if the value (tMonth column) differs from the one below it, the %Change on the second row should be left empty, see sample below and what is expected:

```
+-------+-------+---------+---------+----------+
| Month | tYear | Indices | %Change | Expected |
+-------+-------+---------+---------+----------+
|    01 |  2016 | 166.78  |  NULL   |          |
|    01 |  2017 | 190.51  |  14.2   |   14.2   |
|    01 |  2018 | 197.23  |   3.5   |    3.5   |
|    02 |  2016 | 166.76  | -15.5   |          |
|    02 |  2017 | 188.99  |  13.3   |   13.3   |
|    02 |  2018 | 198.20  |   4.9   |    4.9   |
|    03 |  2016 | 167.34  | -15.6   |          |
|    03 |  2017 | 190.06  |  13.6   |   13.6   |
|    03 |  2018 | 194.60  |   2.4   |    2.4   |
|    04 |  2016 | 169.89  | -12.7   |          |
|    04 |  2017 | 194.24  |  14.3   |   14.3   |
|    04 |  2018 | 203.99  |   5.0   |    5.0   |
|    05 |  2016 | 170.24  | -16.5   |          |
|    05 |  2017 | 196.83  |  15.6   |   15.6   |
|    06 |  2016 | 172.54  | -12.3   |          |
+-------+-------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Using a pseudo programming code:

```
IF tMonth1 <> tMonth2
     Replace %Change with NULL
ELSE
    %Change remains the way it is.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you check if the month below is equal when you have 3 consecutive equal months you will have EMPTY, EMPTY, VALUE. You only want to remove the first appearance?

Comment: @Alejandro, thanks for that, if you look closely, the years differ (i.e. you have 01 for 2016, 2017 and 2018, the same applies to other months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since LEAD and LAG are only supported starting with SQL Server 2012, I would suggest using a self joind and the row_number functionality. Check this example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  tMonth NVARCHAR(2),
  tYear INT,
  pChange DECIMAL(5,2)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
 ('01', 2016, NULL)
,('01', 2017, 14.2)
,('01', 2018,  3.5)
,('02', 2016,-15.5)
,('02', 2017, 13.3)
,('02', 2018,  4.9)
,('03', 2016,-15.6)
,('03', 2017, 13.6)
,('03', 2018,  2.4)
,('04', 2016,-12.7)
,('04', 2017, 14.3)
,('04', 2018,  5.0)
,('05', 2016,-16.5)
,('05', 2017, 15.6)
,('06', 2016,-12.3)

;WITH cte AS(
SELECT  tMonth,
        tYear,
        pChange,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tMonth, tYear) rn
  FROM @t
)
SELECT  c1.tMonth,
        c1.tYear,
        c1.pChange,
        CASE WHEN c1.tMonth != c2.tMonth THEN NULL ELSE c1.pChange END AS pChangeNew
  FROM cte AS c1
  LEFT JOIN cte AS c2 ON c1.rn = c2.rn+1
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your data, you just want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by month order by year) > 1
             then pChange
        end) as expected
from t;
```

Comment: short and sweet - like the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a self `full outer join` with `row_number`:

```
declare @tmp table(tMonth varchar(2), tYear int, Indices decimal(18,6), [%Change]  decimal(18,6))
insert into @tmp values
 ('01', 2016, 166.78,  NULL)
,('01', 2017, 190.51,  14.2)
,('01', 2018, 197.23,   3.5)
,('02', 2016, 166.76, -15.5)
,('02', 2017, 188.99,  13.3)
,('02', 2018, 198.20,   4.9)
,('03', 2016, 167.34, -15.6)
,('03', 2017, 190.06,  13.6)
,('03', 2018, 194.60,   2.4)
,('04', 2016, 169.89, -12.7)
,('04', 2017, 194.24,  14.3)
,('04', 2018, 203.99,   5.0)
,('05', 2016, 170.24, -16.5)
,('05', 2017, 196.83,  15.6)
,('06', 2016, 172.54, -12.3)
select t1.*, case when t1.tMonth <> t2.tMonth then null else t1.[%Change] end as [%Change_replace]  
from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tmonth) as id ,* from @tmp
) t1
full outer join( 
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tmonth) as id ,* from @tmp
) t2 
on t1.id = t2.id+1
where t1.id is not null
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: that was quick and excellent, am deeply grateful! I just had to change a few lines of code and it worked perfectly well. I am running year on year changes for a series of years and months.